# How can I perform a present modally segue on a view controller that is presented modally?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

This might sound kind of weird.

I have a view controller, let's call it `VC1`, that is presented modally as a form sheet.

When the user taps a button in `VC1`, a picker shows up as an action sheet. When the user selects a particular item and tapping "Done" on the action sheet, I want to present another VC (`VC2`) modally.

Let me show you the action sheet:

[image]

So I added a "Present Modally" segue that connects `VC1` and a `UINavigationController`. This `UINavigationController` has `VC2` as its root view controller. The segue has a presentation of "Form Sheet" and a "Flip Horizontal" presentation.

When I test my app, this warning appears in the console and no view controller is presented at all:

> Warning: Attempt to present   on  which is already presenting (null)

And I was like "What the heck is it talking about? How can `VC1` be presenting null?" The weird thing is that it uses `null` (which is terminology from C# and Java) instead of `nil` (Which Swift uses).

I tried different transitions and presentations. But the same message appears. I also tried removing the `UINavigationController` and directly presenting `VC2`. This time, the error message changes to:

> Warning: Attempt to present   on  which is already presenting (null)

How can I present `VC2` modally?

Comment: You can`t present  vc modally on another vc which is modally presented itself. What you can do: dismiss VC1 and then present VC2 on the same host vc

Comment: @Elena But after some trying, I just found out that I can call `dispatch_after` to solve this problem. I will post an answer.

Comment: @Elena Can you explain this?

Comment: You're right, that is not true what I said before. The correct answer would be that you can`t present to modal VC's on the same host simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying, I found out that calling `dispatch_after` like this and performing the segue solves the problem. I don't know why, though.

```
dispatch_after(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("someIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

Maybe this is due to some kind of action sheet magic.

Comment: What is `self` in this case?